# Mock Constructor in ES6 class in NODE using SINON

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, supertest

service.js

```
Class ClassWithConstructor {
   constructor(arg1, arg2) {
        super();
        this.param1 = arg1;
        this.param2 = arg2;
    }
   getInfo() {
    //returns promise
  }
}
```

controller.js

```
export function getData(req, res) {
   const svc = new ClassWithConstructor.ClassWithConstructor(req.user.param1, req.user.param2);

   svc.getInfo()
   .then(result => {
            return respondWithSearchResult(res, 200, result, 'success');
        })
        .catch(err => {
           //return error
        });
}
```

For unit test getData() method I need to mock the line `const svc = new ClassWithConstructor.ClassWithConstructor(req.user.param1, req.user.param2);`

I am using Sinon for mocking. I have been trying for a long. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you need to mock constructor? I don't think so.

Comment: const svc = new ClassWithConstructor.ClassWithConstructor(req.user.param1, req.user.param2);

This line calls the constructor. So when the method is tested, I do not want the original constructor to be called, but a mocked method should be called.

Comment: Provide the completed code you want to test.